# Why are all caching attempts a miss with Memcache and Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

When logged in I see a statistics for memcache hits, but this always shows 100% miss. A couple of questions come up:

1. If there are cookies set, i.e. session cookie while logged into drupal, does drupal even check memcache?
2. If it doesn't check memcache, and the 100% miss would theoretically prove this, whats the point of the memcache stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the connection to Memcache server was timing out. Fixed connection issues and all is working as expected.